# What's the spiral pattern on this satellite?

Tags: artificial-satellite, identify-this-object

I was looking through old saved urls and when an old Johns Hopkins Applied Physics Laboratory press release link didn't work, it sent me to the PageNotFound page, where I saw the image below.

It seems to relate to a spacecraft or actually [a whole project called Transit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_(satellite)), (and a design failure, but I'll split that off as a separate question).

**Question:** What is the spiral pattern on the outside of this satellite that is also repeated on the inside, all the way to the center?

- image url: http://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/images/Home/Transit-Design-Failure.jpg
- page url: http://www.jhuapl.edu/home/PageNotFound/

According to the page:

> **Page Not Found**
>
> “You learn more from failures than from successes.”

[image]

([non-annotated copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10Bml.jpg))

Comment: Related: [What was the design failure that Johns Hopkins Applied Physics Laboratory is alluding to?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27658/12102)

Comment: I don't see *that is also repeated on the inside*

Comment: @JanDoggen  "repeated on the inside" is the spiral wire lead shown on the inside of the top piece (broken) being held by someone off-camera.

Comment: See also [Why were the antennas on the spherical surface of some early satellites spiral-shaped?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30563/12102)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The satellite shown is an early development/test version of the Transit navigation satellites, probably [1](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/transit-1.htm) or [3](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/transit-3.htm). (Transit 2 had a double helix pattern)

The spiral pattern is a "logarithmic helical antenna".  Source: Page 7 at this [link](http://www.jhuapl.edu/techdigest/views/pdfs/V13_N1_1992/V13_N1_1992_Hoffman.pdf)

> The  Space  Department  needed  to  develop  several  novel  antennas 
>   to  radiate  the  Doppler  signal  to  the  ground.  The  first  Transits  used  an  APL-invented  spherical  projection  of  a 
>   logarithmic  spiral.

This [document](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a066299.pdf) states that the antennas were "silver-painted on". (page 28 of the pdf)

[image]

Comment: I'll look into and perhaps ask separately about the reason that the antenna needs to be spiral separately.

Comment: I've now done so. [Why were the antennas on the spherical surface of some early satellites spiral-shaped?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30563/12102)