# What was the design failure that Johns Hopkins Applied Physics Laboratory is alluding to?

Tags: artificial-satellite, failure, identify-this-object

I was looking through old saved urls and when an old Johns Hopkins Applied Physics Laboratory press release link didn't work, it sent me to the PageNotFound page, where I saw the image below.

It seems to relate to a spacecraft or actually [a whole project called Transit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_(satellite)), and a design failure.

**Question:** What is likely to be the design failure that APL is alluding to here? I can see that this object is broken, but I don't know if there is a particularly interesting story behind this, or if it's just an old photo that was handy, like the cute [Stack Exchange panda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TfaR.jpg).

- image url: http://www.jhuapl.edu/Content/images/Home/Transit-Design-Failure.jpg
- page url: http://www.jhuapl.edu/home/PageNotFound/

According to the page:

> **Page Not Found**
>
> “You learn more from failures than from successes.”

[image]

**note:** according to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27657/12102), this is likely to be an "early development/test version of the Transit navigation satellites."

Comment: I've used the `identify-this-object` tag since we probably don't need a separate "identify this failure" tag.

Comment: @JCRM no need to re-post a *known broken link* from the past.

Comment: You're right, I mistakenly thought you were asking about the contents of the link - without knowing what the link was it's impossible to say whether it contains clues as to where it might now be found.

Comment: @JCRM It's the mesmerizing, TwilightZoneesque spiral pattern on the satellite [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gFzW.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSNcB.jpg), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzsqz.jpg).