# Will SpaceX use a special launch maneuver for the SAOCOM 1B mission?

Tags: spacex, launch, history, launch-trajectories

Teslarati's [SpaceX sets date for first Florida launch of its kind in more than half a century](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-florida-first-polar-launch-half-a-century/) explains that something different will happen. For those that want to read the article first, I've used the spoiler alert utility for the surprises.

Spoiler alert: hover cursor over block quote to reveal what it will be:

> They will launch into a polar orbit from the East coast of the US

See answers to this question for more background on that maneuver from that launch site:

> [How does one dogleg from Florida to a sun-synchronous orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21343/12102)

**Question:** Will they need to do that special trajectory maneuver mentioned in the second spoiler alert in order to do the thing in the first spoiler alert?