# Most dog-legged launch?

Tags: launch, mission-design, record, dogleg-maneuver

There are enough questions about dogleg maneuvers that there is now a [dogleg](/questions/tagged/dogleg) tag, but the definitive dogleg answer is @JakeBlockers (linked below) which includes images of a dogleg from Florida that avoids flying over Cuba (after a self-destructed launch dropped debris on them).

Here I'd like to ask **what was the most dog-legged launch?**

Since unlike satellite trajectories, detailed launch trajectories are not in some handy numerical database. Information is inexact and in different forms for different launches. So I won't specify the largest angular deviation or worst delta-v or worst payload penalty. For this question I'll leave it as simply "most dog-legged" and let the answers sort themselves out.

---

Images below are from [@JakeBlocker's answer to *How does one dogleg from Florida to a sun-synchronous orbit?*](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/21355/12102). See also

- [Which launch was the first to use a dogleg maneuver?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27651/12102)
- [Are there any dog-leg hot-spots? Where are dog-leg maneuvers used most frequently?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30559/12102)
- [dog-leg, dogleg, or dog leg?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/387446/217285)

> Here's a picture of a falcon 9 launch, I do not believe it's from NROL-76. The maneuver occurs towards the center of the screen. And here's a picture of a dog's leg just to compare :)
>
> [image: Here's a picture of a falcon 9 launch, I do not believe it's from NROL-76. The maneuver occurs towards the center of the screen.] [image: And here's a picture of a dog's leg just to compare :)]